# Can I change settings of a video when opening it in HTML

Tags: html, css, html5-video, fullscreen

On my video page in HTML I made the picture clickable so it go's to the video i'm testing.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="column">
    <a href="../video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <span></span>
    <img src="../photo/Law Abiding.jpg" alt="Law" class="image" style="width:80%">
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I change the video to display full screen after clicking it and changing the video controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of linking page directly to video you can link to another page which embeds the video and you can set the attributes you want. And it's not possible to set video to fullscreen without the user action being made on page. Users can go fullscreen by clicking the fullscreen button on the bottom right corner where a frame icon is displayed. You can full screen whole of your page too: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/10/Let-Your-Content-Do-the-Talking-Fullscreen-API